# what wrong on scroll top functionality

Tags: javascript, scroll, back

Is this correct way to add scroll top functionality?

```
function toTop(){
  const topTrigger = document.querySelector('.back-to-top');

  topTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  });
}
toTop();
```

Comment: 1. Does it work? 2. Have you tried it across multiple devices? 3. Have you tested it across multiple browsers? 4. Do you need to release the EventListener??

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working correctly. Somehow if it doesn't work, try calling `toTop()` when the DOM content is loaded:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  toTop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="up">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="bi bi-chevron-double-up"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 300) {
    document.querySelector(".up").style.display = "flex";
  } else if (window.screenY < 300) {
    document.querySelector(".up").style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

This will work, Here JS is used to toggle the display.